# PassportJS Express req.user not persisting in Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, passport.js, backend

I am using React and Express. Only the React is hosted on heroku and I am hosting the Express server locally. With Express I am using Passportjs with MongoDB.

The problem is that React clien t works well on local deployment, however once I deploy my React App on Heroku it does not work well propertly. 
When using my deployed React app, I can register a user but I cannot log in a user. It does not return error and POST("/login") returns "Successfully Authenticated" back to me and when I try to access req.user using axios it returns nothing back when it should be returning the user.

**React Code**

```
const getUser = () => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:3001/user",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        {
          console.log(res.data);
          if (res.data.username != null)
            setMessage("Welcome " + res.data.username);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const loginTheUser = async () => {
    await axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:3001/login",
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.data === "Successfully Authenticated") {
   
        history.push("/");
      } 

      console.log(res.data);
    });

    await getUser();
  };
```

**Express code**

```
// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "https://my-herokuapp.com",
    ], // <-- location of the react app were connecting to
    credentials: true,
  })
);


app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser("secretcode"));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./passportConfig")(passport);
```

```
//Login
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      console.log("Unsuccessful login");
      res.send("Unsuccessful login");
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        {
          console.log("Login success");
          res.send("Successfully Authenticated");
        }
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

```
//Register
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, async (err, doc) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (doc) res.send("User Already Exists");
    if (!doc) {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

      const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });
      await newUser.save();
      res.send("User Created");
    }
  });
});
```

```
//get User
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user); // The req.user stores the entire user that has been authenticated inside of it.
});
```

Passport config

```
const User = require("./user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (result === true) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
      const userInformation = {
        username: user.username,
      };
      cb(err, userInformation);
    });
  });
};
```